# About multipart/form-data?

Tags: mime, form-submit, multipart, enctype

Is there another `multipart/form-data` like `enctype` but not `form-data`?

**EDIT**

Especially,what others are used in web applications?

Comment: So you want another content type that's just like an existing content type but different?  Right.  Maybe you can give some more explanation on what you want to do and why multipart/form-data is insufficient?

Comment: Web apps that submit forms use multipart/form-data.  Unless they use AJAX, in which case they might submit the data as XML or JSON.

Answer (score 8):

**multipart/byteranges** is used for partial data.
However this is typically used in the Server -> Client direction (whereby form-data is in the other direction).  The "Form submitting" tag and other hints in the question indicate that this may not be the kind of encoding the OP is looking for.

other multipart subtypes include

- multipart/mixed
- multipart/alternative
- multipart/parallel

Which too would be more likely (but not necessarily) used in the context of server responses rather that of client requests.

Here is a more comprehensive list of [**MIME multipart subtypes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_subtypes) from Wikipedia